# Git clones via Gerrit and SSH not identical?

Tags: git, ssh, clone, gerrit

I've ended up taking a good clone from SSH then pushing it to a brand new Gerrit with `git push origin --mirror`.

Since a new clone from the new server doesn't exhibit this problem, the root cause is likely the ACL from the old Gerrit server.

---

Cloning the same repo through two different protocols yield different clones.

```
$ git clone ssh://sshuser@server:22/home/gerrit/gerrit2/git/MyProj thru-ssh
Cloning into 'thru-ssh'...
remote: Counting objects: 3685966, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (552960/552960), done.
remote: Total 3685966 (delta 3102302), reused 3685965 (delta 3102301)
Receiving objects: 100% (3685966/3685966), 760.21 MiB | 3.24 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3102302/3102302), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (41972/41972), done.

$ git clone ssh://gerrituser@server:29418/MyProj thru-gerrit
remote: Counting objects: 2955171, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (2955171/2955171)
remote: Total 2955171 (delta 2465234), reused 2934649 (delta 2465234)
Receiving objects: 100% (2955171/2955171), 721.03 MiB | 1.77 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2465234/2465234), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Checking out files: 100% (41972/41972), done.
```

For instance, a tag is missing on the one cloned through Gerrit.

```
$ cd thru-ssh/; git tag -v v3.11; cd -
object 6e4664525b1db28f8c4e1130957f70a94c19213e
type commit
tag v3.11
tagger Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org> 1378154778 -0700

Linux 3.11
gpg: Signature made Mon Sep  2 13:46:22 2013 PDT using RSA key ID 00411886
gpg: Good signature from "Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: ABAF 11C6 5A29 70B1 30AB  E3C4 79BE 3E43 0041 1886

$ cd thru-gerrit/; git tag -v v3.11; cd -
error: tag 'v3.11' not found.
```

Not surprisingly, more than half of a million objects and 60MiB of data are missing on the one cloned through Gerrit.

```
$ cd thru-ssh/; git count-objects -v -H; cd -
count: 0
size: 0 bytes
in-pack: 3685966
packs: 1
size-pack: 858.63 MiB
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0 bytes

$ cd thru-gerrit/; git count-objects -v -H; cd -
count: 0
size: 0 bytes
in-pack: 2955171
packs: 1
size-pack: 799.94 MiB
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0 bytes
```

Git fsck on the server doesn't report any problems, although it reports 15 more objects than a clone made through SSH.

```
sshuser@server$ git fsck --unreachable --strict --no-reflogs
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (3685981/3685981), done.
Checking connectivity: 3685981, done.
Other repos in the same server are cloning through Gerrit without this problem.
```

What could be causing this?

---

I tried pushing the contents to a local repo and the result is even weirder:

```
$ cd thru-ssh/
$ git tag -v v3.11
object 6e4664525b1db28f8c4e1130957f70a94c19213e
type commit
tag v3.11
tagger Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org> 1378154778 -0700
[…]
```

Tag exists in "thru-ssh" repo. Let's push it to my local empty repo.

```
$ mkdir ../emptyGit ; cd emptyGit ; git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/scpark/GitRepos/emptyGit/.git/
$ cd ../thru-ssh/
$ git remote set-url origin /Users/scpark/GitRepos/emptyGit/
$ git push origin —all
Counting objects: 2954795, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (461359/461359), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2954795/2954795), 627.14 MiB | 50.27 MiB/s, done.
```

Aaand the tag is gone...

```
$ cd ../emptyGit/
$ git tag -v v3.11
error: tag 'v3.11' not found.
```

Halp :(

Comment: Is there something wrong with your access right to `refs/tags/*`

Comment: I have read access to it, and all the objects are owned by gerrit user on the server

Comment: If you run `git ls-remote ssh://hostname/path/to/repo` against both repositories, what's the difference in output?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the commit that the tag is pointing to then the tag will not be downloaded from git as you don't have access to the commit.

So if you don't have access to refs/heads/release/* and the tag is pointing at a commit that is not reachable from any of the refs/heads/xxx you have access to then that tag will not be downloaded.

If the tag is pointing to a commit that is not part of the clone.. for instance you could accidentally have pushed a branch refs/head/master (notice no s) and once again the tag must be pointing to a commit that is not reachable from the commits you have access to.